# Remove multiple joins to same table with where

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am stucked at below situation. Need expert advice.
I have 3 tables, login_details,deleted_login_details and custom_fields as below.
login_details structure = deleted_login_details
custom-fields have : user_id,custom_name,custom_value

I want following result.
I want only those users who fulfilled all where conditions with multiple joins on custom_fields table. Example

```
select user_id from login_details union deleted-login_details  as login_table
join
custom_fields as f1 on f1.user_id = login_table.user_id 
join
custom_fields as f2 on f2.user_id = login_table.user_id 
where
f1.custom_name = '1' and f1.custom_value in (1,2,3)
and 
f2.custom_name = '2' and f2.custom_value in (4,5,6)
```

So only those records should come who have custom_name =1 and value as above and custom_name=2 and value in above.
But I want this using only 1 join to custom_fields table.

Like as

So only 1 ,2 should get and no 3 as 3 dont have custom_name =1 record

[image]

Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please apply some formatting so your question/query/result is readable?

Comment: Sure, its by mistake.one moment please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append to your query `GROUP BY user_id`. This has the effect that multiple user_ids become one row entry.

Additionally append `HAVING COUNT(user_id)=2`. As you've `GROUP BY user_id` the count of them represents that the number of field matches.

Comment: Yes Dan, but I need to eliminate extra joins to same table but keeping correct data.Is that possible.

Comment: It is as simple as possible. [EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) schemas do add a lot of joins. You do need one for each field name.

Comment: Thanks @danblack, your EAV concept solved my most of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't understand your use of `UNION`; I'll focus on the question.)

```
FROM `deleted-login_details` AS login
JOIN custom_fields AS cf ON cf.user_id = login.user_id
WHERE IF(name = '1', value IN (1,2,3),
                     value IN (4,5,6))
```

If you need more than 2 choices, then consider the `CASE .. WHEN .. END` syntax.